# Give a index to a new summoned object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to give it a variable. so like when it summoned, it given a index by the summoner script.

I try to make the object to get the variable from the spawner. but it was to long and complicated. I hope you have a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways this can be accomplished. As you appear to be a beginner, I will offer two simple solutions that should help you along your way.

1. You can add the spawned object to a list. When you want the index of that object, just use `int indx = myList.IndexOf(myObject);`. This will return the index of your object in the list.
2. Create a script and add to you prefab (in editor or programmatically) and add an int with the name indx. When you instantiate the object, you can access the script and add a value onto that number. E.g:

.

```
int amountToSpawn = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < amountToSpawn; i++)
{
   GameObject newSpawn = Instantiate(spawnObject, transform.position, transform.rotation;
   newSpawn.GetComponent<AttachedScript>().indx = i;
}
```

*Note* It doesn't have to be a for loop for this second method. But it shows how each new object would have a new index number.

There are other methods for assigning an index to objects created, but they are dependent on what you are creating and using them for. Anyhow, these two simple methods should point you in the right direction.

Happy coding!